# Access - "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" with VBA function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get error *Data type mismatch in criteria expression* when running this query.
See below what I tried. Question is how can I investigate further to find the error?

```
SELECT qCalls.Senso, qCalls.Data, qCalls.Ora, qCalls.NumeroPulito, qCalls.Durata, qContactsOutlookPerCallsUNION.Azienda, IIf(Count([NOME])=1,First([NOME]),"**nomi multipli**") AS Nome2
FROM qCalls INNER JOIN qContactsOutlookPerCallsUNION ON qCalls.NumeroPulito = qContactsOutlookPerCallsUNION.Numero
GROUP BY qCalls.Senso, qCalls.Data, qCalls.Ora, qCalls.NumeroPulito, qCalls.Durata, qContactsOutlookPerCallsUNION.Azienda
ORDER BY qCalls.Data DESC;
```

Both `qCalls` and `qContactsOutlookPerCallsUNION` run correctly when called separately.
There is no criteria expression (= WHERE clause, as I understand it) in my SQL. I then think the data type issue is on the `INNER JOIN` part but:

- `qCalls.NumeroPulito` is a string, comes from: `CStr(Replace([Number],"+39","")) AS NumeroPulito`
- `qContactsOutlookPerCallsUNION.Numero` is a string, it comes from: `IIf(IsNull([Phone]),Null,PulisciTelPerCalls([Phone])) AS Fisso` where `PulisciTelPerCalls()` is a VBA function which returns a *string*

Answer (score 1):

Without being too sure, I believe the error is caused by the inline if statement `IIF()` since it checks both conditions anyway, thus could be sending a null value to the function.

I think you should scrap the `IIF` and handle null values in the function.

```
Public Function PulisciTelPerCalls(ByVal Phone As Variant) As String
    If IsNull(Phone) Then
        PulisciTelPerCalls = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If

    'rest of method 
End Function
```

Then just call the method directly:

```
PulisciTelPerCalls([Phone]) AS Fisso
```

Answer (score 1):

*CStr* on a string doesn't make sense. Try removing it and use *Nz*:

```
Replace([Number],"+39","") AS NumeroPulito
```

and

```
PulisciTelPerCalls(Nz([Phone])) AS Fisso
```

or

```
IIf(IsNull([Phone]),"",PulisciTelPerCalls([Phone])) AS Fisso
```